# Does null value occupy any memory in BQ table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery, 70% of the fields contains null value. I wanted to know whether null value occupy some memory, if so I could switch to NoSQL database. I also wanted to know your suggestions whether BQ is good to go with this kind of data (where 70% of them are null) or NoSQL. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> Null values for any data type are calculated as 0 bytes.

See [Data Size Calculation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data)